# The General Lorentz Transformation in 3+1D

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#/media/File:Lorentz_boost_any_direction_standard_configuration.svg ,

we have: $\ \mathbf{r}'=\mathbf{r}_{\bot}  +\gamma( \mathbf{r}_{\|}-\mathbf{v}t) \;\;, t'=\gamma(t-\frac{\mathbf{v}.\mathbf{r}}{c^{2}})$

If $\;\;\;\mathbf{v}\bot \mathbf{r}\Rightarrow\mathbf{v}.\mathbf{r}=0$

This means that $\;\;t'=\gamma t$

Why in this case time does not depend on space?

Comment: Hint: to what are $r_\parallel$ and $r_\perp$ respectively parallel and orthogonl?

Answer (score 2):

This means that two simultaneous events on a plane normal to $\:\mathbf v\:$ in one system are simultaneous in the other system.  That is planes normal to $\:\mathbf v\:$ are geometrical loci of mutual simultaneity.

Comment: The problem is that we always speak of space-time as a non-separable block!

Comment: Moreover if we consider the inverse transformations, we find that t= (1/γ)t', there is a certain asymmetry between the reference frames!